# Laravel 5.5 keep getting 419 post error on ajax call after several attempts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.5

I would really appreciate some help on this. I tried every solution that every one suggested on other posts, including this: [Laravel 5.5 ajax call 419 (unknown status)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466167/laravel-5-5-ajax-call-419-unknown-status) and this [Ajax LARAVEL 419 POST error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472812/ajax-laravel-419-post-error) solutions.

But I keep getting 419 error even if I set the csrf_token meta tag on the head section:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And before ajax post call, I set up the ajax csrf_token like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

And after that I send the csrf_token in ajax data as a variable like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url     : "/getCompare",
        type    :"POST",
        cash    : false,
        data    :{ id : id,_token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},
        success :
           function( response ) {
              $("#compare_products").html(response);
             }
        });
```

The application of the page is in such way that the user repeatedly requests for ajax calls to compare products. It works fine in lots of attempts but in a specific scenario, it throws 419 error. The scenario is sometimes when I push a button about 3 minutes after page load, it gives me that error. Or sometimes it gives the error on the third or fourth attempt. And after reloading the page the problem fixed but it keeps sending that error again in the way that I explained.

My question is why is this happening? is csrf_token expired after 3 minutes or what? And I don't want to add an exception in verifyCsrfToken middleware. 
Whats the solution to this problem?

**PS:** 
leorent's answer is quite right. But after uploading my project into an actual online server. the problem was gone already. 
I don't know why but this problem is because of windows and running the laravel project locally in local host. 
The csrf token session expires frequently on widows localhost server. Don't worry, after uploading the project into an actual server, your problem with csrf is going to be solved automatically.

Comment: Keep a closer eye on your network tab. Make sure that you send the same session token for each request. Also make sure there are no conditions under which the csrf token gets refreshed while in the  same page.

Comment: @apokryfos is it suppose to send the same csrf_token in every request?

Comment: Yes the session token and the csrf token should remain the same unless you manually change them in the back end.

Comment: @apokryfos I checked the csrf_token and it turns out it is the same token in every request.This error happens when I wait for a couple of minutes and then make the request. If I send the request repeatedly it doesn't give me that error.

Comment: How long is your session set to last for when idle? (It should be in the `config/session.php` file under `lifetime`)

Comment: @apokryfos It is about 6000.

Comment: @apokryfos Is it ok to do it in a way below, as "leo instanceof Kelemendi" suggested?

Comment: If it works then do it. I dislike sending it with the headers anyway.

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you for your help. so appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the meta tag with an id:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

then on your ajax call:

```
     $.ajax({
         url     : "/getCompare",
         type    :"POST",
         cash    : false,
         data: {'id': id, "_token": $('#token').val()},
         type: 'POST',


         success: function (response) {

         },
         error: function (response) {

         }
     });
```

Comment: Should I set up the ajax csrf headers in this method before ajax call or not?

Comment: @SalarBahador if you sent token like this there is no need for headers

Comment: @Thank you, the problem fixed. But is it a best practice to do it this way?

Comment: @SalarBahador mark as answered then, it does not really matter at this point.

Comment: This is better than using `.ajaxSetup` because this way if you send a CORS request you won't accidentally send CSRF tokens along with it (which might be a security issue)