# Why is my route returning 404 error Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, request

I am currently trying to make an AJAX request for a type of form post, but the PHP parse script I am trying to send the data to is returning a 404 error that I can see through Chrome developer tools. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ajax_post(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/products/parse.blade.php";
    var productName = document.getElementById("productName").value;
    var quantityInStock = document.getElementById("quantityInStock").value;
    var pricePerItem = document.getElementById("pricePerItem").value;
    var totalValueNumber = quantityInStock * pricePerItem;
    var route = "productName="+productName;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    hr.send(route);
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}

</script>

<div class="container-fluid form-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="productName" id="productName" placeholder="Product Name" class="form-control" required>    
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" name="quantityInStock" id="quantityInStock" placeholder="Quantity in Stock" class="form-control" required> 
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" step="0.01" name="pricePerItem" id="pricePerItem" placeholder="Price per Item" class="form-control" required>  
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Create Product Listing" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ajax_post();">

            <hr>
            <div id="status"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using Laravel, and both this view `products.create` and the file I am trying to use to parse the data, `products.parse` are both in the `products` directory of my views folder. But, when I try to submit, all I get is a response of "processing" in the status div, and a 404 error for the route `mydevsite.dev/products/parse` in Chrome's dev console.

My thought it that I needed to define a route, so I added:

```
Route::post('/products/parse', 'ProductController@parse');
```

Which returns

```
return view('products.parse');
```

But this just changes my error to a 419. I'm thinking it has something to do with CSRF field, but I'm not sure how to include that because it my html is not a form, but simply has form elements. Why is my route returning a 404 or 419 error, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You're posting to wrong URL.

It must be like this :

```
var url="/products/parse";
```

and you need to send CSRF token as well(else it would cause 419 error), which is described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) :

put this meta tag inside your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then access it by jQuery like this:

```
$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
```

Comment: The CSRF token wouldn't cause a 404

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn yeah, but he didn't post CSRF token, so it would cause another problem.

Comment: CSRF token isn't always required.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Obviously, He is not writing an API so CSRF token is required, unless he has disabled CSRF protection

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting the wrong route. This variable

```
var url = "/products/parse.blade.php";
```

should be this

```
var url = "/products/parse";
```

You want to call the route that is defined here

```
Route::post('/products/parse', 'ProductController@parse');
```

You are trying to call the blade file that the route is returning which isn't the correct way to do it. Plus that file isn't located in your public directory.

---

You could try using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) instead. It would look something like this:

```
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = 'processing...'
let form = new FormData()

form.set('one', '1')
form.set('two', '2')

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  // Credentials may or may not be required. 
  // It depends if cookies are needed or not.
  credentials: 'include',
  body: form,
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
  }
}).then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = text
  })
```

Comment: @hoolakoola have you tried using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) inestead?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn using raw XHR won't cause 419 error :) the CRRF token thing, as I said, is the problem

Comment: @HamidrezaKalantari looks like you are right https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472812/ajax-laravel-419-post-error

Comment: @HamidrezaKalantari yes that was the issue, I added `hr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));` and it solved it. Thank you both.