# Import Excel to Database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to Import an excel file and save the info into the database table. Right now I'm getting an error

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.

All the tutorials I saw didn't get this error and I'm doing it the same way, I don't know what the issue is. I'm using this package `"maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.3"`.

This is my vue

```
<el-form :action="'impteachers/import'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <el-input type="file" name="file"/>
    <el-input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</el-form>
```

This is the controller

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'file' => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx'
    ]);

    $path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
    $data = Excel::load($path)->get();

    if ($data->count()) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value){
            $arr[] = [
                'NOMBRE' => $value->name,
                'CEDULA' => $value->card,
                'CARNET' => $value->scard,
                'TIPO-USUARIO' => $value->user_type_id,
                'CORREO' => $value->email,
                'PASSWORD' => $value->password,
            ];
        }

        if (!empty($arr)) {
            User::insert($arr);
        }
    }
    return redirect('/imports');
}
```

These are the routes in web.php

```
Route::resource('impteachers', 'ImportTeacherController');
Route::post('impteachers/import', 'ImportTeacherController@import');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try submitting to `'/impteachers'` only like this

```
<el-form :action="'/impteachers'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <el-input type="file" name="file"/>
    <el-input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</el-form>
```

And set your route to this

```
Route::post('/impteachers', 'ImportTeacherController@import');
```

Comment: That was a copy/paste mistake, I do have them both as import in my project

Comment: Oh okay. Well I would update your question so others don't try to correct the same thing. Maybe try remove the `/import` and try submitting to `/impteachers` only. I will update my answer.

Comment: I tried this, but now I'm getting a `419 Page Expired`

Comment: @Nancy, 419 typcially has to do with csrf_token. check this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472812/ajax-laravel-419-post-error) to learn more.

Comment: I have both `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` and `@csrf` in my head, and if I add anything related to `csrf` in my form the page doesn't load, no error but not loading.

Comment: @Nancy, well I suggest making a new stackover flow question regarding the 419 alarm when submitting your form since it is different from you original issue.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've resolved it (for now at least)

Comment: Awesome, if my answer fixed your original issue could please check it for me? Im trying to get these points lol