# Laravel / Airlock AJAX login - 419 (unknown status)

Tags: laravel, laravel-airlock

I'm trying to do a cross origin login request and everything except logging in is working.  So if I go to api.example.com and log in with the laravel app and then go to www.example.com I can get the user by calling the /api/user end point (setup as part of airlock).  What I'm failing to do is log in via AJAX with username / password.  Here is the JS used:

First I call `setCSRFCookie()`

```
    function setCSRFCookie() {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', domain+'/airlock/csrf-cookie');
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.send(null);
    }
```

Then I call `loginUser()`

```
    function loginUser() {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let params = 'username=m@example.com&password=password';

        xhr.open('POST', domain + '/login', true);
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
        xhr.send(params);

    }
```

I'm getting a `419 (unknown status)` which appears to be Laravel's response for an invalid CSRF token.  I looked at the actual request and both `APP_NAME_session` and `XSRF-TOKEN` are being passed as part of the request.  The only thought I had was that the `/login` default auth route isn't setup for this and I need to do one under `/api/login` so it's served by the airlock middleware.  I appreciate any help you can give.

Laravel 6.12.0
Airlock 0.1.0

Comment: Post request requires `X-CSRF-TOKEN` check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472812/ajax-laravel-419-post-error).

Comment: @Tpojka Thank you.  The Airlock docs make it seem like passing the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` cookie is enough with the /login endpoint but maybe I've misunderstood.

Comment: I haven't use Airlock tbh, but 419 is code that suggests csrf token hasn't used on POST request. I'd try with `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', 'VALUE_FROM_csrf_token()_HELPER_FUNCTION');` before `xhr.send(params);` line.

Comment: Thanks again @Tpojka.  I'll give that a try but my understanding is the whole selling point to Airlock is to set cookies that get automatically sent with the request (so they can be HTTP only).  The documentation specifically calls out calling `/airlock/csrf-cookie` to set the cookie before making the request.  With that said the cookie is named `XSRF-TOKEN` not `CSRF-TOKEN`.  I'll try doing a /api/login (which would get handled by the Airlock middleware) too.

Comment: I have the same issue with a small twist, I am using laravel 7 with the airlock, on PHP artisan serve and using localhost:8000 it's working fine but when I use laravel valet and use a test domain then I get 419 which is CSRF MISMATCH error, I set up airlock.php file in config my .test domain but still get same CSSRF MISMATCH 419 error. any help?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `api.example.com` is included in `config/airlock.php` like this

```
'stateful' => [
    'localhost',
    'api.example.com'
],
```

And request middleware should be `auth:airlock`