# Getting 419 (unknown status) while submitting post ajax in laravel

Tags: laravel, csrf-token

Getting 419 (unknown status) while submitting post ajax in laravel with the following code

```
 url: '/forksnippet/saveforksnippets',
            type: 'POST',
            data:
            '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
              $(this).serialize()
            ,
            beforeSend: function(result){
        $(".saveforksnippetbutton").attr("disabled", true);
        $(".saveforksnippetbutton ").html('Auto saving...');
        },
            success: function(result) {

                $(".saveforksnippetbutton ").html('Auto Saved');


            }
        });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ajax LARAVEL 419 POST error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472812/ajax-laravel-419-post-error)

Comment: See this answer specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46493409/3429323

Comment: When i am submitting  form like this everything is working fine but when calling ajax with keyup. getting this problem...

Comment: The code that you posted is incomplete and invalid. Post the correct code