# I have to complete the real-time table using ajax but I am sticking with an error which is CSRF token mismatch error

Tags: ajax, laravel, csrf

I am A PHP developer and currently moving towards Laravel framework as per my task I have to complete the real-time table using ajax but I am sticking with an error which is CSRF token mismatch error please help me to resolve the error I am posting shortcode only

**ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.toggle-class').change(function() {

                var status = $(this).prop('checked') === true;
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                var csrf=$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');



                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: '/package/status',
                    data: {'status': status, 'id': id, 'XSRF-TOKEN': csrf},
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log('success '+data);
                    }
                });

            })
        })
```

**Route Path**

```
Route::post('package/status', [App\Http\Controllers\PackageController::class,'status']);
```

**Controller code**

```
 public function status(Request $request){


        $Package = package::find($request->id);

        $Package->status = $request->status;

        $Package->save();

        return response()->json(['success'=>'Status change successfully.']);
    }
```

I don't know why it is showing me CSRF token mismatch when headers contain tokens once solved I can have some real-time action.

Comment: CSRF token is generally passed as `_TOKEN` in Laravel. Does this work: `data: {'status': status, 'id': id, '_TOKEN': csrf}`?

Comment: no! I tried. it's not working

Comment: yeeeee it's working!! thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ajax LARAVEL 419 POST error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472812/ajax-laravel-419-post-error)

Comment: He already have csrf token in the ajax setup, He needs to add csrf meta tag inside the head of the master/parent layout. @miken32

Comment: @miken32 its not working

Comment: @Psycho Exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 data: {'status': status, 'id': id, '_token': '{{csrf_token()}}'},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
   ..  .. .. 
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
   ..  .. .. 
</head>
```

Add this meta tag in the header of your master layout for csrf token which will be matched with the csrf token of your ajax call and thus it will solve your problem hopefully. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: '/package/status',
    data: {'status': status, 'id': id, '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
    success: function(data){
    console.log('success '+data);
    }
});
```

Change `XSRF-TOKEN` to `_token`
And change data like this `{{ csrf_token() }}`

Answer (score 0):

Just use _token for the  csrf variable

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.toggle-class').change(function() {

                var status = $(this).prop('checked') === true;
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                var csrf=$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');



                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: '/package/status',
                    data: {'status': status, 'id': id, '_token': csrf},
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log('success '+data);
                    }
                });

            })
        })
```